# Proving Cauchy Riemann Equations for General Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

How would one prove that Cauchy-Riemann equations hold for any holomorphic functions? I used the definition of complex differentiability to achieve the second equation ( $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$) by approaching the limit from different sides, but I cant seem to understand where the first equation($ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$) comes from.

Comment: Some context would help greatly here, in particular what the first and second equations are.  Yes, anyone could look them up, but in general there is no guarantee that they would find the same presentation as what you are looking at.

Comment: I think the two C-R equations are from : limit of the real part from two directions and limit of the imaginary part from two directions.

Comment: Cauchy-Rieman relation defined complex functions which could be complex differentiable, holomorphic functions follows later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the definition of the complex differentiability of $f$ at $a$ implies the existence of a $\phi : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ continuous at $a$ such that $\phi(a) = f'(a)$ and
\begin{align*}
f(z) - f(a) = \phi(z)(z - a).
\end{align*}
Treating $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\phi(a)$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Thus $f$ is totally differentiable at $a$, and there exists a Jacobian $J$ such that $J(f;a)(z) = wz$ for some complex number $w$.

In other words, the local effect of a complex differentiable function is multiplication by a complex number (a rotation and a dilation).

The result follows quickly: since the linear approximation of a complex differentiable function $f = u(x, y) + v(x, y)i$ at $x + yi = z \in \mathbb{C}$ is given by the Jacobian
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(z) & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(z)\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(z) & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(z)
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}
and transformations that represent a rotation and a dilation are of the form
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & -\beta \\
\beta & \alpha
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}
we obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(z) = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(z) \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(z) = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(z).
\end{align*}
Hope this helps.